# Passing a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, user-defined-functions

How do you pass a variable to a function located in a different php file using redirect in CodeIgniter?

for example,

```
$name='John'

redirect('home/login($name)');
```

Is this correct?

Comment: That would just pass the literal string `$name`. Variables aren't interpolated inside single-quotes. Use double-quotes or concatenate the `$name`. I'd use something like: `redirect("home/login/{$name}");`.

Answer (score 4):

No.You are using it on the wrong way.Try it like

```
redirect('home/login/'.$name);
```